# A button result in a mysqli_fetch_array cannot get through to the next page

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a php page with this code that passes a variable of a button to next page:

```
<div><center><table>
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<td><form action= display.php  method= 'post'><input type='hidden'      
          name='projectid'     value=".$row['projectid'].">
          <input type= 'submit' name= 'type'   
          value= 'View/Amend Project Details'></form></td>\n";
}
echo "</table></div>";
```

I have  this on my next page in a table:

```
$projectid= $_POST['projectid'];
echo "<td>" . $row['projectname'] . "</td>";
```

I still cannot see the problem, any idea?

Comment: Are you fetching `$row` on the next page? What errors are you getting? Please do read the help section of this site, and add more info

Comment: what is $row on next page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to use the `$row` on your second page, and it isn't set there.

You have to either do the mysqli query again, or transfer the value of $row['projectname'] through the form, using a hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
       echo " name='projectid' value=".$row['projectid']."> value= 'View/Amend Project Details'>\n";
    }
```